# Blender Freezes Whole System

Tags: interface, error

I recently started learning Blender and I'm really enjoying it, but it keeps freezing my system. I started a blender tutorial to create a donut and my setup keeps freezing. Every window freezes and starts flickering, but it seems that the desktop underneath still works, I can start any software, but the blender window stays on top. I'm using Manjaro and if I press F12 I can shutdown and restart my laptop from the terminal. However, this happens quite often and I cannot use Blender anymore.

My setup is the following:

- Operating System: Manjaro Linux
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
- KDE    Frameworks Version: 5.70.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.0
- Kernel Version: 5.7.0-3-MANJARO
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
- Memory: 7,7 GiB of RAM

I checked `top` and it didn't seem like Blender was using too much memory or CPU. I'm open to any suggestions as I can hardly use the software and couldn't find anything when googling around.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that since blender only becomes unresponsive and doesn't crash there aren't any logs.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your graphics card. What do you have and which driver do you use?

Comment: I have an Nvidia Geforce GTX  960M and I'm using the nvidia prime 440xx driver. I also have an intel HD Graphics 530 and as far as I can tell that uses the default drivers.

Comment: can you watch the graphic card's temperature with the nvidia-settings? Maybe it glitches out because of overheating?
Alternatively: Does the glxinfo command show that the Nvidia card is actually in use?

Comment: When I started using blender the temp went up 2-3 degrees (32C-->35C) so it's not overheating. Glxinfo gives the following: https://pastebin.com/i398LJMY It's possible only the intel card is in use.

Comment: That's strange... it looks as though the nvida card is not used and still you can use nvidia-settings to monitor the card's performance? Is it possible that this has to do with the nivida-optimus power saving settings?

Comment: Actually, I read around a bit after this and found that since my gpu uses nvidia440 and is an optimus card if I use prime-run glxinfo I get the Geforce card as expected: https://pastebin.com/7ikNGuLq So not sure, it really might have something to do with the optimus power saving settings.

Comment: did you try prime-run blender as well?

Comment: Well now I did and that actually seems to have solved the issue! I've tested it yesterday for a couple of hours and blender didn't become unresponsive at all. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as a solution :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with the NVIDIA-Optimus powersaving technology, which is somewhat commonly found in laptops.
As the linux driver runs applications per default with the internal Intel graphics adapter, perfomance issues are to be expected.
Running blender with the prefix command `prime-run`, forces activation of the dedicated 3D adapter and should resolve the performance issues.

Comment: Low framerate would be a "performance issue to be expected". Freezing, flickering, and window draw order being broken are not. I've also been having similar issues with Blender on Manjaro over the last few weeks, with freezes, desktop hangs, various buffers flashing, and no discernable cause from VRAM, processing power, or thermal limits. I suspect something got broken in a driver or compositor update.